# Does hashdump also dump domain creds when run on a domain controller

Tags: hash, metasploit, meterpreter

If I understand correctly, `meterpreter`'s `hashdump` dumps the content of the SAM file. Domain users should be in the AD database on domain controllers, which I understand is NTDS.dit .

On my test network, if I run `hashdump` on a domain joined workstation I don't get any domain users as expected.

However on my domain controller, running `hashdump` appears to also dump my domain users.

Why would people bother fetching NTDS.dit and using extraction tools like `esedbexport` + `dsusers` when they can just `hashdump`?

I fear I'm missing something. Could someone explain more clearly if `hashdump` on a DC does indeed dump *all* domain accounts and hashes, and what the difference is between that and extracting them from NTDS.dit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smart_hashdump` will query a Domain Controller's lsass to dump hashes, but the regular `hashdump` will only get what is available in the SAM database for users (usually IT admins) that log into the domain-controller server directly (whether on-console, via RDP, or some other remote mechanism).

`domain_hashdump` uses the NTDS.dit file to extract all Domain Users, including historical ones. See -- https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/post/windows/gather/credentials/domain_hashdump -- for more information

Comment: Thanks. Could I just ask for clarification on the difference between what `smart_hashdump` gets from lsass, and the contents of NTDS.dit? Will `smart_hashdump` and `domain_hashdump` both give me all users/hashes?

Comment: No, only domain_hashdump gives you all hashes for all Domain Users including archived. It's possible that smart_hashdump will, but I doubt it and would not rely on it. They would have to be utilized to be in-memory like that.

Answer (score 0):

No you are correct, simply running hashdump whilst logged onto a domain controller via psexec (set target to 1 (powershell) will dump the domain user accounts from the NTDS. I have tested this in real time, creating accounts in AD but not logging onto the DC as them (standard user via users and computers mmc) and re-running hashdump picks them up.

Comment: I'm not sure this adds more to what the accepted answer says. Did you intend to say something different or are you confirming what was said?

Comment: This does feel more like a comment than an answer.